# how to pass parameter to service in angular from textbox

Tags: api, service, angular8

```
getStatus(id):Observable<any>{
let param1 = new HttpParams().set('postId',id);
return this.httpclient.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/",{params:param1});
  }
```

**I am calling this API and parameter is passed `/?postId=2` in this format but i want parameter in `/2` this format.how to get it?**

Comment: Just append it with the url if you want it that way instead of making `HttpParams`

Comment: You want it like `this.http.get('someurl/2')` ?

Comment: okay got it  now error is NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Comment: Your response must be an object as a whole. you need to push that into an array to bind on HTML using ngFor or you could filter out the data part if it is an array.